# What do the credits mean after defeating the Ender Dragon in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm pretty sure everyone knows what I'm talking about. When you defeat the Ender Dragon and jump into the center portal, these people or unknown beings start talking to each other through text. And I'm guessing they're talking about you, or the "player". There are even some parts that are "censored" or "glitched" that you cannot read. Every time I see this, it gets me thinking:

Who are we?
And why am I here?

Does anyone know what the credits at the end mean? And what they are talking about?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are referring to the [end poem](https://minecraft.wiki/w/End_Poem). It seems to have been created through commission from Notch, the creator of Minecraft, by Julian Gough. People do find it to be interesting and different.